# Default public view not working?

Tags: 2013, view

This is really simple scenario with frustrating results.

I have a list with a few columns, and I'd like the default view to sort by the first column, alphabetically.

When I first entered the data, I did not do so alphabetically. (Banana, Apple, Cabbage instead of Apple, Banana, Cabbage, for example) Rather than go back and reenter everything alphabetically, I created a view that sorts the first column so and set it to Default View (Public).

My list is present on my SP site's homepage. The problem is that when anyone navigates to the homepage, the items in the list are **not** displayed alphabetically. This means that my default view isn't doing anything, right?

I am able to go to List -> Modify View -> [My Default View] and that sorts everything alphabetically. Why do I have to do this? Shouldn't the default view sort my list by... well, default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views on web part pages are disassociated in a way from the underlying list. As you make changes to the list view, any web part pages containing those views don't see the changes.

Simply edit your web part page by toggling the view on the web part to something different, hit Apply, and change it back to your desired view and click OK. Save your page (check it in and approve it if required).

Comment: Thanks! My view is now alphabetical by default. I think I understand now - in order to make a web part page (i.e. my standard homepage) realize that I want a certain List view, one needs to: 
1. Page tab -> Edit
2. Click on List
3. Web Part tab -> WP Properties
4. List View -> [choose desired view]

Answer (score 0):

The webpart in the home page is not a link to the view. It is a copy. So changes in the view does no affect the home page. You need to modifiy de order in the properties of the webpart in the home page.